# Get value of first td element in same row as button

Tags: jquery

So I have a table structured like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td><?php info displayed with php ?></td>
             <td><?php info displayed with php ?></td>
             <td><?php info displayed with php ?></td>
             <td><?php info displayed with php ?></td>
             <td><?php info displayed with php ?></td>
             <td><?php info displayed with php ?></td>
             <td><a href="#" class="usr-edit">Edit</a></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is get the value of the Id from the first column when the user clicks edit. If you would like to laugh at my failed attempt, here it is:

```
$('.usr-edit').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();

    alert(a);
});
```

Comment: use `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();`

Comment: @guradio it worked! I never thought of going for the tr then the first row.

Comment: @j08691 it was just alerting an empty box, no data.

Comment: Ug, disregard my previous comment. The link has no previous siblings. You'd need to go up at least one level in the DOM first.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy i gave an answer glad to help happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.usr-edit').click(function() {
  var a = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();

  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="usr-edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

you can use dom reference in with table element to go get the cell you want

```
var td = this;
var tr = this.parentNode;
var firstTd = tr.cells[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

```
$('.usr-edit').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).parent().find('td:first-child').text();
    console.log(a);
});
```

EDIT: To find the `tr` parent, this is how you can do it.

```
$('.usr-edit').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
    console.log(a);
});
```

And a dirty way

```
$('.usr-edit').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first-child').text();
    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: Sir the parent of element with class `usr-edit` is a `td` this would be wrong

Comment: Good catch! Updated! :)

Comment: happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class on your `<tr>` like `<tr class="yourClass">` and use:

```
$('.yourClass').find('td:first-child').text();
```